# Does anyone know where I can get SOLR patch for Magento Enterprise EE 1.12.0.2?

Tags: magento, solr

Does anyone know where I can get SOLR patch for SOLR version 4.4 for Magento Enterprise version 1.12.0.2?

I tried to find the MagentoCommerce.com support system, but there no longer seems to be a support ticket system there.

Thanks in advance and apologies for placing what is probably a duff question, but I am getting desperate since I dont want client to suffer.

Comment: Perhaps http://magento.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for your question (and it seems that you already have an answer there from @philwinkle)

Comment: The EE support still exists: http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/ee/

Answer (score 0):

The patches are available in the following link:

[Enerprise Edition (EE) Patches for Apache Solr](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/solr-ee-patches)